# Conditional Probability.

Tags: probability

I have been trying to solve this question:

Suppose we roll a standard fair die twice. Suppose we are also told
that the sum of the numbers rolled is $6$. What is the probability that a $4$ was rolled
at least once?

I got an answer of $\frac{2}{5}$ is this correct?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  There are $5$ equally probable ways to roll a $6$,  $2$ of which include a $4$.

Answer (score 1):

There are $36$ possibilities for the ordered pair of the numbers shown on the dice. Of these, exactly $5$ give a sum of $6$:

$$(1,5)\qquad(2,4)\qquad(3,3)\qquad(4,2)\qquad(5,1)$$

These are all equally likely, and exactly two of these include a $4$. Thus you are correct, and the answer is $2/5$. Another (albeit more tedious) way to do this problem would be using [Bayes' rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_rule).

Answer (score 0):

at least once is always the probability of 1 - none. Calculate the probability of none then subtract it from 1! 1- 3/5 = 2/5